# Query AWS SNS Endpoints by User Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Simple question, but I suspect it doesn't have a simple or easy answer. Still, worth asking.

We're creating an implementation for push notifications using AWS with our Web Server running on EC2, sending messages to a queue on SQS, which is dealt with using Lambda, which is sent finally to SNS to be delivered to the iOS/Android apps.

The question I have is this: is there a way to query SNS endpoints based on the custom user data that you can provide on creation? The only way I see to do this so far is to list all the endpoints in a given platform application, and then search through that list for the user data I'm looking for... however, a more direct approach would be far better.

Why I want to do this is simple: if I could attach a User Identifier to these Device Endpoints, and query based on that, I could avoid completely having to save the ARN to our DynamoDB database. It would save a lot of implementation time and complexity.

Let me know what you guys think, even if what you think is that this idea is impractical and stupid, or if searching through all of them is the best way to go about this!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't the ability to have a "where" clause in ListTopics.  I see two possibilities:

1. Create a new SNS topic per user that has some identifiable id in it.  So, for example, the ARN would be something like "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789:know-prefix-user-id".  The obvious downside is that you have the potential for a boat load of SNS topics.
2. Use a service designed for this type of usage like PubNub.  Disclaimer - I don't work for PubNub or own stock but have successfully used it in multiple projects.  You'll be able to target one or many users this way.

Answer (score 0):

According the the `[AWS documentation][1]` if you try and create a new Platform Endpoint with the same User Data you should get a response with an exception including the ARN associated with the existing PlatformEndpoint.

**It's definitely not ideal**, but it would be a round about way of querying the User Data Endpoint attributes via exception.

```
    //Query CustomUserData by exception
    CreatePlatformEndpointRequest cpeReq = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest().withPlatformApplicationArn(applicationArn).withToken("dummyToken").withCustomUserData("username");
    CreatePlatformEndpointResult cpeRes = client.createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq);
```

You should get an exception with the ARN if an endpoint with the same `withCustomUserData` exists.

Then you just use that ARN and away you go.

Comment: You can create users with the same user data, so testing for an error when creating an endpoint with the same user name does not work.